# Calculate prorata share with MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I have a SSAS cube that shows Investors and their investment value in funds.  The fund value and prorata shares are in fact table.  I've created a calculated measure that simply multiplies fund value * share.  The problem comes in the Total line.  The row marked as WRONG is what shows now.  The row marked RIGHT is what I want to show.

```
Investor    Fund Value  Share   Investor Value
Investor 1  100,000     0.4     40,000
Investor 1  200,000     0.3     60,000
Total       300,000     0.7     210,000   <== WRONG
Total                           100,000   <== RIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

Max answer is the way to go if performance might be a problem (precalculation). It's possible to solve the prorarta using MDX Calculated members (performance might be an issue if your dimensions are big).

The issue to go further into this solution is I need a dimension where the 100'000 and the 200'000 Fund Values are difference (e.g. [Share] .). Can you describe your dimensions ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few months old, but I would use a scope statement to overwrite that cell with the correct calculation. Check this out: http://www.bidn.com/articles/mdx-and-dmx/94/mdx-scripting-with-scope-statement To view the article requires a login, but its free.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: create new calculated field (write an expression) in DSV (in the corresponding fact table) of your olap DB. And after that use this field in the measure (aggregation type SUM).

Comment: I've simplified the data model to highlight the issue.  Both Fund Value and Investor are many-to-many relationships, so a calculated field is not possible.